# How to disable ssl verification when generating documentation with sphinx ? (working behind a proxy)

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, python-sphinx

Generating the documentation gives me the following error:

```
loading intersphinx inventory from https://docs.python.org/3/objects.inv...
WARNING: failed to reach any of the inventories with the following issues:
intersphinx inventory 'https://docs.python.org/3/objects.inv' not fetchable due to <class 'requests.exceptions.SSLError'>: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='docs.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/objects.inv (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

I work behind a company proxy.

Is there any way to disable ssl verification ? Like anaconda does with: `conda config --set ssl_verify false` ?

Answer (score 2):

Per the Sphinx documentation, you can modify one of two variables in `conf.py` to specify a path to your cert or turn off verification all together.

1. `tls_verify` (boolean) - If true, Sphinx verifies server certifications [LINK](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-tls_verify)
2. `tls_cacert` (str) - A path to a certification file of CA or a path to directory which contains the certificates [LINK](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-tls_cacerts)

---

It would look like this in your `conf.py`:

```
# uncomment this if you don't want to verify at all
# tls_verify = False

tls_cacert = "/path/to/cert"
```